# I can't access my newly created website after deploying it to Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

So, I have deployed my web app on Azure's App service, but I have a few errors that I don't get. I even created an SSL certificate for my website but still nothing got solved.
This is the result when I access it.

[image]

This is a picture that shows that my custom domain doesn't have a binding.

[image]

I can't access the "Add binding" at all. it shows me this "" when I hover on it. Also, I watched a video on YouTube and the guy didn't even need to add binding but he was able to access his website without issues. So what have I done wrong?

Comment: Why you are adding SSL certificate to the App?Are you not able to access the Azure App service directly after deployment ?

Comment: What is the framework and version of the Web App? Could you please share the code repo if possible.

Comment: My web app is built using the Angular framework v 18.14.0. I'm unable to share the code repository, but I can provide you with the GitHub .yml file, which contains details about the build and deployment process.
https://prnt.sc/_6AR32bGigV_
https://prnt.sc/S_GyGeHiDyyQ

Comment: Have you updated any DNS entries to point your address at the webapp?

Comment: Yes I have, I ran a diagnosis on Azure, and i found multiple errors that i don't even know how to solve lol.
The major ones are
"Identified URLs that could not be assigned to the site."
and this
https://prnt.sc/Zpab1d2KKczT

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.

Comment: `I watched a video on YouTube` , can you please share the link which you have followed.

Comment: Are you deploying to Azure Windows or Linux App Service ?

Comment: The `yml` file which you have shared is not accessible...

Answer (score 1):

> My web app is built using the Angular framework v 18.14.0.

The latest [angular version](https://angular.io/guide/releases#actively-supported-versions) available is `v16.2`.

```cs
ng version
```

[image]

- When we run `ng build`,  `dist` folder will be created with the required files.

[image]

- Instead of all the files from the root directory,you can simply set the `dist` folder path in `yml` file.
- So, you can remove `zip` and `Unzip` from the `yml` file.

```cs
   - name: Zip artifact for deployment
      run: zip release.zip ./* -r
```

and

```cs
    - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
    run: unzip release.zip
```

Thanks @[Nicola Delfino](https://nicolgit.github.io/how-deploy-angular-app-to-azure-appservice-running-linux-from-github/) for the clear steps.

***My `yml` file:***

```cs
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - AngNodeOct

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: dist/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'AngNodeOct'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_AECDE0FFE5DB4FF8A2892052DD061D08 }}
          package: .
```

- In `Configuration` => `General Settings`, add the below start up command.

```cs
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/my-ang-app-oct --no-daemon --spa
```

***Output:***
[image]

[image]

[image]